# Why does random.choice() sometimes not make any choice?

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to create some logic that will reliably choose between two things. But the following code seems to have some serious bug in it because often there is no choice made.

```py
import random
while True:
    if random.choice([0, 1]) == 0:
        print("Right")
    elif random.choice([0, 1]) == 1:
        print("Left")
    else:
        print("Why do we ever reach the else?")
```

The output looks like this:

```
$ python3 random.choice.broken.py 
Why do we ever reach the else?
Why do we ever reach the else?
Left
Why do we ever reach the else?
Left
Right
Left
Left
Why do we ever reach the else?
Why do we ever reach the else?
Right
Why do we ever reach the else?
Left
Right
Right
Why do we ever reach the else?
Left
Right
Left
Left
Right
Left
Right
Right
Right
Why do we ever reach the else?
Left
Why do we ever reach the else?
Why do we ever reach the else?
Right
```

I'm sure there must be a reasonable explanation. But I can't find it online or in the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: It always does. It reaches the else clause when it chooses 1 in the if clause and 0 in the elif clause ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's the nature of your code that's leading to this. You make the random choice AFTER entering the condition. You should ideally make the choice before entering the `IF` condition and then refer to it later.

```
import random
while True:
    ch = random.choice([0, 1])   #<-----
    if  ch == 0:
        print("Right")
    elif ch == 1:
        print("Left")
    else:
        print("Why do we ever reach the else?")
```

```
Left
Right
Right
Right
Right
Left
Right
Left
Right
Left
Right
Left
Left
Left
Right
Left
Right
Left
Left
Left
Left
```

---

#### Analyzing your current code behavior

To explain further, let's analyze why you would reach the specific print statements in your current code -

1. `print("Right")` - If your **first choice** is equal to 0
2. `print("Left")` - If your **first choice** is NOT equal to 0 and your **second choice** is equal to 1.
3. `print("Why do we ever reach the else?")` - If your **first choice** is NOT equal to 0, and your **second choice** is NOT equal to 1.

> Note: Since you are mentioning `random.choice([0, 1])` in your conditions itself without storing it in a variable, each instance of the choice is a separate one. Therefore your first random.choice is different from the second random.choice.

Hope that explains the current behavior as well.

Comment: The key insight here is that a second choice is made. There is no need to store the choice in a variable. Simply delete the existing `else` branch and replace the `elif` line with `else:`. I'd normally write `if random.random() < 0.5:` for a coin flip but whether that's more clear is debatable (and it uses 7 bytes of the PRNG instead of just 1).